# Swiftのオーバーライド関数の存在条件について

Tags: swift, spritekit

とても初歩的な質問になります。

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

// lastを用意しておく
var last:CFTimeInterval!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {}

// 赤い四角を、画面中央から上に向かって打ち出すメソッド
func shoot() {
    let square = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 40))
    square.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(40, 40))
    square.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
    square.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 100)
    square.physicsBody.linearDamping = false
    self.addChild(square)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    // lastが未定義ならば、今の時間を入れる。
    if !last {
        last = currentTime
    }

    // 1秒おきに行う処理をかく。
    if last + 1 <= currentTime {

        self.shoot()

        last = currentTime
    }
}
}
```

こちらのコードは
https://qiita.com/mochizukikotaro/items/6d3a7e445ea67e5b4643
から引用させていただいております。また、若干古いバージョンになりますが、あまり突っ込まないでください。

色々なサイトを閲覧していて、オーバーライドは親クラスを継承した際に、無理やり（？）引数や処理の異なる同名の関数を定義する行為だと心得たのですが、そうなってくると、上に引用したコードのように、親クラスが何なのかよくわからないケースが多すぎます。
極端な話、Xcodeの初期コードですら読めません。
ですので、上に引用したコードなどを参考に、一体何をオーバーライドしているのかお教え願いたいです。
本当に初歩的な質問をしてしまい申し訳ございません。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「オーバーライドは…引数…の異なる同名の関数を定義する」と言う記述があるのですが、オーバライド(override…上位の権限を持ったものが下位のものの下した決定を覆す…と言うのが本来の意味)とオーバロード(overload…過積載が本来の意味)が混同されているように思います。もう一度オーバライド・オーバロードの違いをしっかり調べて、ご質問内容をリファインしないとご期待の回答を得にくいのではないかと思います。(正直私は何を聞きたいのかさっぱりわかりません。)「親クラスが何なのかよくわからない」と言うのもなんのことかわからない部分の一つです。「引用したコード」では、親クラスが`SKScene`であるのは自明だと思うのですが? 「親クラスの何をオーバライドしているのかわからない」と言う意味でしょうか? 十分理解できない概念に関する用語が不正確になるのは仕方ありませんが、中途半端に省略されてしまうと、得られる回答も中途半端でわかりづらいものになってしまうでしょう。「初歩的な質問」がダメなんてことは全然ないと思うんですが、一体何を聞きたいのかよくわからないのは困りものです。もう少しご自身の質問を読み直して、何を聞きたいのかがより多くの人に伝わるよう書き直してみることをお勧めします。

Comment: 例えば、「自分はこれくらいなら、オーバライドが理解できているように思う」と言う出来るだけ簡単な例とかは示せないですか? それに比べて掲載されたコード(あるいは「Xcodeの初期コード」)のどの辺がわかりにくいか、とか言った書き方で、どの部分がわかりにくいのか絞り込むことができれば、適切な回答がしやすくなると思います。

Comment: あやふやな点多き質問で申し訳ありません。ですが、あなたの下さった回答の中に私の得たいものはありました。意図を汲んでくださりありがとうございます。SkSceneというのがスーパークラスであるということが分かっていなかったのが私にとっては大きな問題でした。そのことが知れるだけでも、今後の学びの糸口になりますので、非常に感謝します！